# Hazelcast Management Center Scripting feature

Tags: hazelcast

I am deploying Hazelcast management center in a virtual lab to manage clusters within the same network.

In the documentation, I noticed the "Scripting" feature, allowing the admin to execute Javascript, Ruby, Groovy, or Python codes on the clusters.

But I cannot find much reference on what Javascript codes can be executed?

Is it possible to execute os commands on the clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to run OS commands from scripts.

You can access the Java objects (including `java.lang.Runtime`) from the script.

The Javascript uses JDK provided engine for instance - Rhino for Java 6-7, Nashorn for Java 8+.

**Nashorn**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/scripting/using-java-scripts.htm#JSJSG116

```js
Java.type("java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime().exec("touch test.txt");
```

**Rhino**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jstojava

```js
importClass(java.lang.Runtime);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("touch test.txt");
```